# ST_IsPlanar returns true even for invalid 3D polygons

Tags: postgis, sfcgal

We are trying to find a way to validate 3D polygons with arbitrary rotation. It seems like you should be able to do this with the function [`ST_IsPlanar`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsPlanar.html), because it claims to "not drop the z index", but we are finding that it always returns true, even when the polygon is clearly invalid, due to a point being way out of the plane formed by the other points.

We understand a polygon being "valid" to mean that to mean that all of the points of the polygon fall in a 2D plane, even if this plane is not parallel to the XY, XZ or ZY axes.

According to the documentation, the function is supposed to not drop the z-index, so that why do both of these polygons return true?

```
/* Valid 3D polygon */
SELECT 
    ST_AsText(ST_Polygon(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(1 1 0, 1 4 0, 4 4 0, 4 1 0, 1 1 0)'), 2154)),
    ST_IsPlanar(ST_Polygon(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(1 1 0, 1 4 0, 4 4 0, 4 1 0, 1 1 0)'), 2154)
);
```

```
/* Invalid 3D polygon */
SELECT 
    ST_AsText(ST_Polygon(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(1 1 0, 1 4 0, 4 4 9999, 4 1 0, 1 1 0)'), 2154)),
    ST_IsPlanar(ST_Polygon(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(1 1 0, 1 4 0, 4 4 9999, 4 1 0, 1 1 0)'), 2154)
);
```

As you can clearly see, the invalid polygon has one of its points lifted very far out of the plane created by thee other points. But yet, `ST_IsPlanar` returns true regardless.

This may not be a relevant detail, but out of curiosity, we looked in the [PostGIS SFCGAL source code for this function](https://oslandia.github.io/SFCGAL/doxygen/group__capi.html#ga7ee133c5038b546faad5fc9b6ba27eaf), and noticed that it has a precondition that `IsValid()` returns true, but this function only works in 2D.

Are we simply doing something wrong here? It seems that this function, despite apparently working on 3D geometries, is not actually validating them properly.

Comment: Based on a bit of further digging, I believe that you are confusing the isValid function in sfcgal with ST_IsValid in Postgis. The functions in sfcgal are standalone and make no reference to the Postgis or GEOS ones. The sfcgal version definitely works on PolygonZ datatypes, whereasa ST_IsValid, which comes from GEOS, only works in 2 dimensions. The source is here: https://github.com/Oslandia/SFCGAL/blob/7f96d756dab03d3cac61543e4208dc7d45265511/src/algorithm/isValid.cpp Perhaps I should convert this into an answer?

Comment: Further, I get ST_IsPlanar = 'f' for the 2nd one, as you would expect.  What version of sfcgal are you using? I have 1.3.5.The actual is_planar code is at https://github.com/Oslandia/SFCGAL/blob/7f96d756dab03d3cac61543e4208dc7d45265511/src/capi/sfcgal_c.cpp#L804.

Comment: Sorry, the actual algorithm that calculate if a Polygon with z values is planar is here: https://github.com/Oslandia/SFCGAL/blob/7f96d756dab03d3cac61543e4208dc7d45265511/src/algorithm/plane.h#L132. It's a pretty cool approach.

Comment: @JohnPowell Thank you for your repsonse, I can't seem to check the postgis_sfcgal version, `select postgis_sfcgal_version();` is just returning a "function does not exist" error. but the extension is definitely installed, I have even used other sfcgal functions.

Comment: How about, `SELECT postgis_full_version();`. I'm not sure if you need to run `SET postgis.backend = sfcgal` first, but, it won't hurt. How did you install it, as a matter of interest? I had to recompile postgis, after buiding sfcgal, to get it to work, on Ubuntu 18.04, for what it is worth, as the packaged version does not seem to contain sfcgal,ie, `CREATE EXTENSION postgis_sfcgal` fails.

Comment: It's actually quite strange, I can't seem to call any SFCGAL functions today... I will have to go have a chat with our IT department. But it is reassuring to know that you are getting the correct answer regarding the invalid polygon.

Comment: Good luck. It sounds like you might need to reinstall it. Yes, ST_Planar is definitely working as expected. And, thanks for the question, I am learning C++, so, being forced to look at source code is very helpful :D.

Comment: @JohnPowell The sfcgal extension somehow got assigned to a temp schema, not really sure what happened there or how, but remaking it `WITH SCHEMA PUBLIC` made it work again. Our SFCGAL version is 1.2.2, so it is likely just out of date. We will get it upgraded check again.

Comment: It turns out that it was indeed caused by an older version, a database with an SFCGAL version of 1.3.2 does return the correct value.

Comment: Great. I'll write up a slightly more coherent answer at some point. There isn't much documentation on the sfcgal functions, so it might help someone else.